# Mysql / Mariadb user grant to multiple database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant

Would like to grant permission to a user on multiple databases in single command. I am getting syntax error when I try

`grant all on abc.*, xyz.* TO 'user'@'10.10.0.10';`

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use multiple grant statements, one for each database:

```
grant all on abc.* TO 'user'@'10.10.0.10';
grant all on xyz.* TO 'user'@'10.10.0.10';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use single database or *.* for all databases in single statement like below:

> grant all on abc.* TO 'user'@'10.10.0.10'; --- For abc database.

> grant all on *.* TO' user'@'10.10.0.10'; --- for all databases